# How to evaluate the following derivative related to norms?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

$T$ is bounded linear operator between two Hilbert spaces $X$ and $Y$. If we define $$f(x) = \|Tx-y\|^2+ c \|x\|^2$$ Where $c$ is a constant and $y \in Y$. Then Clearly $f$ is a convex functional and has unique minimizer. Now First order criteria for unique minimizer is $$f'(x)h = 0 \quad \forall \quad h \in X$$ Now How to prove that $$f'(x)h = 2(\langle Tx-y, Th\rangle + c \langle x, h\rangle)$$ Please help me.

Comment: by applying the definition of the derivative. This is a one- or two-liner.

Comment: begin by write $f(x+h)-f(x)$ and don't forget that $||x||^2 = <x,x>$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x+h)-f(x) &=&  \langle T(x+h)-y,T(x+h)-y\rangle+c\langle x+h,x+h\rangle \\ && -\langle T(x)-y,T(x)-y\rangle-c\langle x,x\rangle \\ &=&2\langle T(x)-y,h\rangle+2c\langle x,h\rangle+\langle T(h),T(h)\rangle+c\langle h,h\rangle \\ &=& df'(h)+O(h)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

since $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{{\langle T(h),T(h)\rangle +c\langle h ,h\rangle}\over \|h\|}=0$$